# I need an advice about Multi Customer Deployment for ReactNative App

Tags: react-native, mobile, deployment, publish, release-management

My team will make an application for business solution. We need a way for deployment because we have customers more than 5, but we want to use just one build for our app. And we have a problem, because we don't want to publish our app to appstore or playstore, we want to serve directly our customer's clients. And there is a handicap, because our customer's networks are restricted. We have searched for a lot of ways, but none of us can take us to the conclusion.

Can you guide us if anyone live in a similar situation?

Thank you,

Mert

Comment: *We have searched for a lot of ways, but none of us can take us to the conclusion.* you should probably state the things that you have looked at otherwise people may waste time giving answers that you have already discounted.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, use just one build for your app, upload and share it.

https://www.diawi.com/